# Multiple canvases in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas, background-image, layer

I have two canvases, one with panels or the buttons the player can interact with and one that acts as its background. I separated two canvases because the aspect ratio of the background image is 16:9 so when the aspect ratio is changed it becomes stretched. So I set the canvas with panels and buttons to match with height so that it will not scale when the screen's aspect ratio is 19:9 and others and I set the background canvas to match with the width of the screen so the background image will just scale according to the width changes which is typical in most of the mobile phones nowadays.

The problem is the background canvas is in front of the canvas with panels and buttons. so the only thing that I can see when I build and run it in my phone is the background because it is in front. What should I do to bring the background canvas to the back?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using the `Sort Oder` in the `Canvas` component. I set the background to `0` and the canvas with panels and buttons to `1`. Meaning that the canvas will render the background first and then the other panel next.